# Uploading files are very slow in my PHp project

Tags: php, file-upload

I am working on a osCommercre project, in which there pages for uploading the reference files, we have given functionality to upload the file upto 100 MB size, 
Now the client Complains me that customers are complaining for the late upload of files, 
what should i do to increase the upload speed?

Comment: I assume you've eliminated the possibility that your client's connection to the server is to blame?

Comment: Whats that u r talking about Mike?

Comment: Have some courtesy  to mention the reason for -ve rating..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you investigate what the real bottleneck is? This is all about upload speed, and the most obvious cause is that the clients have not enough bandwidth. Even if they use a fast ADSL, they could still have low upload speed (the "A" in ADSL stands for "Asymmetric", i.e. fast download, but slow upload).

For example, with a typical (for Europe) upload speed of 512kb/s, to upload a 100MB file it will take at least 26 minutes, assuming full speed (which is not the usual case)...

Comment: I feel the same as u said, I must say this to that nuthead

Comment: @OM The Entity: "What About the US people" What's that supposed to mean? Palantir's answer is perfectly sensible and the figure quoted is obviously intended to be illustrative - what **actually** matters is the bandwidth between your client and your server. If you don't know what that is, then go and find out.

Comment: @OM The Eternity What are you talking about? Symcbean's response, while perhaps slightly curt, is simply pointing out the real issue which has been touched on by every other answer/comment here. If you truly have no knowledge of network connections and/or bandwidth I strongly suggest you commit yourself to learning these topics as they are integral to web-development.

Comment: @MIKE Now Thats The way to Reply and Suggest/Recommend Something, Thanx MIKE Yes you are correct at this point, but i dont have idea for where to start it from and and what is good enough knoweldge regarding networking...

Answer (score 2):

What upload speed do they have? In my experience the user usually complains even when they have maxed out there own available upload speed from their ISP. Ask them what advertised speed they do have, and then check if they have maxed out that speed (remember that 1 MB = 8 Mbit).

If they have a lot of bandwidth, check with the hosting provider/your sysadmin.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do small optimization in your code, however, you can do nothing about files as large as **100 MB** size. Uploading process will be slower with files this size :( Same as the case with sites such as gmail, yahoo, etc.