# php 7.4 file uploads very slow

Tags: php, ubuntu

I am building a audio video archive where I upload Mp3 and Mp4 files through a browser
They are uploading extremely slow and timeout but my winscp program works fine
I have a FiOS 1 GB connection on my server and a separate 1 GB connection on my home computer
I am running ubuntu 20.04 LTS and php 7.4
What am I doing wrong?
Below are my php.ini specs

```
memory_limit = 4095M
file_uploads = On
post_max_size = 1600M
upload_max_filesize = 800M
max_file_uploads = 200
upload_tmp_dir=/phptemp
sys_temp_dir=/phptemp
```

My free command returns the following

```
 free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       49435424     1608652    44537944       43664     3288828    47208036
Swap:       8388604           0     8388604
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uploading files are very slow in my PHp project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3083397/uploading-files-are-very-slow-in-my-php-project)

Comment: Without knowing your client upload method and server handling method, there isn’t much we can do. In front of your PHP process is probably a server such as Nginx or Apache that is getting hit first, too

Comment: It is apache, it appears i will have to use ftp for large files. I have my own server so i can make any adjustments I need. Its it Apache 2.4 php 7.4 Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

In my reading I dont see how I can use standard ajax for uploading video files. I am working on a SFTP plugin for my page